# Problems with joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm currently making an application using C# and I am having some difficulty with joining two tables. To make things more clear here are my table structures

Table 1(List of Employee)

```
| EmployeeID | EmployeeName |
+------------+--------------+
|     1      | John Smith   |
|     2      | Ian Smosh    |
```

Table 2(List of Referrals)

```
| PersonalID | InviterID | InterviewerID | 
+------------+-----------+---------------+
|     1      |   1       |       1       | 
|     2      |   1       |       2       |
```

The output on Datagridview should be

```
| Employee Name | Invites | Interviews | 
+---------------+---------+------------+
| John Smith    | 2       |      1     | 
| Ian Smosh     | 0       |      1     |
```

I am currently able to get the invites but not the interviews at the same time. I am only able to get one.

Here is what I get

```
| Employee Name | Invites | 
+---------------+---------+
|  John Smith   |  2      | 
|  Ian Smosh    |  0      |
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT Table1.RecruiterName AS Name, 
    COUNT(Table2.InviterID) AS Invites, 
    COUNT(Table2.InterviewID) AS Interviews 
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.InviterID = Table1.EmployeeID 
    AND Table2.InterviewerID = Table1.InviterID 
GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

Anyone there knows what's wrong with my code?

UPDATE: I managed to make it a little better but I keep getting

```
| Employee Name | Invites | Interviews | 
+---------------+---------+------------+
| John Smith    | 2       |      2     | 
| Ian Smosh     | 0       |      1     |
```

The entry for John Smith only has 2 Invites and 1 Interview. This is my current code

```
SELECT Recruiters.RecruiterName AS Name, COUNT(Source.SourceID) AS Source, COUNT(Interview.InterviewID) AS Interview 
FROM Recruiters 
LEFT JOIN Hires Source ON Source.SourceID=Recruiters.RecruiterID 
LEFT JOIN Hires Interview ON Interview.InterviewID=Recruiters.RecruiterID
GROUP BY RecruiterName
```

Why is it that John Smith gets a wrong amount in interviews but Ian Smosh is correct.

Comment: You should tag it as sql since it's sql problem not c#

Comment: ohh sorry.. i was using C#.NET and forgot to remove tag xD thanks :)

Comment: Because the 2 invites cause the 1 interview to be counted twice

Comment: Please, show us the tables with correct names and correct records.

Comment: Frisbee was right! I change my answer but Frisbee's version can be faster. Check it!

Comment: sorry for the late reply, im gonna check it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the double join is double dipping
this should work

```
select employee.EmployeeName, inv.count, int.count 
  from employee 
  join ( select InviterID, 
                count(*) as count 
           from referral 
          group by InviterID     ) as inv 
    on employee.employeeID = inv.InviterID 
  join ( select InterviewerID, 
                count(*) as count 
           from referral 
          group by InterviewerID ) as int 
    on employee.employeeID = int.InterviewerID
```

Comment: This Solution Was Spot On! Thanks Frisbee ;) and thanks also to @knagaev for the effort :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Recruiters.RecruiterName AS Name,
(select COUNT(*) from Hires where SourceID = Recruiters.RecruiterID) AS Source,
(select COUNT(*) from Hires where InterviewID = Recruiters.RecruiterID) AS Interview
FROM Recruiters
```

Comment: lemme test this for a while ;)

Comment: dont i need to make it Table2 as Inviters?

Comment: you are messing up the table entries @_@ Table1.InviterID? thats table 2 :( did you check my post ;(

Comment: The Inviters and Interviewers is a column.. not a table.. there are only 2 tables

Comment: I rechecked the names of the tables and corrected, sorry.

Comment: Inviters and Interviewers are aliases for two entries of Table 2.

Comment: thanks :) i managed to make the code work but there is one thing bugging me... ill edit my post

Comment: That double join is going to cause extra rows and bad counts

Comment: 2Frisbee Please, explain your guess.

Comment: 2Frisbee Yes, you're absolutely right. My bad. I need to rewrite query :)