# Want to eliminate duplicate record based on only column value

Tags: mysql, sql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea4d2/1

Here is the SQLfiddle to look at. storepkid 16 is repeated 2 times. But I want it only one time. I tried DISTINCT but it eliminate entire duplicate row so it's not working in this case. What changes do I need to make in query to get proper result? Please help.

NOTE: forgot to mention in initial question that I tried GROUP BY too but it's giving incorrect data in record set result. I tried to use GROUP BY in following ways.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea4d2/20

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea4d2/17

NOTE2: @Gabriel Valdez Timbol, I want result like this. Row with duplicate storepkid should be eliminated.

```
| Storepkid | selldate | 
+---------------+-----------------------+
|     19    |  August, 25 2015 10:00:00 | 
|     12    |  August, 24 2015 19:00:00 | 
|     16    |  August, 24 2015 16:00:00 | 
|     15    |  August, 23 2015 13:00:00 | 
|     17    |  August, 21 2015 10:00:00 |
```

Comment: have you tried using GROUP BY?

Comment: brownie points for providing a fiddle

Comment: wait, can you give us an example of what you want to achieve? and also a sample of table structure? :) draw us one here

Comment: Ok, please provide me couple of minutes to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max` function. Use the below query

```
SELECT p.storepkid, max(p.selldate) AS recentselldate 
FROM 
(SELECT storepkid, purchasedatetime AS selldate 
        FROM t_product_purchase 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT storepkid, starttime AS selldate 
        FROM t_service_purchase 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT storepkid, selldatetime AS selldatetime 
       FROM t_coupon_purchase ) p 
GROUP BY storepkid
order by max(p.selldate)
DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

OUTPUT:

```
| Storepkid |        selldate           | 
+---------------------------------------+
|     19    |  August, 25 2015 10:00:00 | 
|     12    |  August, 24 2015 19:00:00 | 
|     16    |  August, 24 2015 16:00:00 | 
|     15    |  August, 23 2015 13:00:00 | 
|     14    |  August, 21 2015 13:15:00 |
```

Check the [DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea4d2/60)

Comment: It's like magic.... thank you very very much for your valuable help. It's working fine as it should be. That's other thing that I am still trying to understand magic of MAX() in query...hahaha

Comment: Haha...Hope u understand the magic soon ;)...Glad I helped :)

Comment: The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column.
[MAX()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Here Is Correct Code i tried it at your fiddle
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea4d2/7)

I also ran into a similar problem ---> [Joining Two Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178452/4947143)

```
 SELECT p.storepkid, p.selldate AS recentselldate FROM (SELECT storepkid, purchasedatetime AS selldate FROM t_product_purchase UNION ALL SELECT storepkid, starttime AS selldate FROM t_service_purchase UNION ALL SELECT storepkid, selldatetime AS selldatetime FROM t_coupon_purchase) p GROUP BY p.storepkid ORDER BY recentselldate DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ran your query but storepkid 19 as last sale on 25th Aug and that record is not displaying in record set.

Comment: ohh yeah.. well i guess we can fix that ;) gimme a a few mins to give you revised code

Answer (score 0):

Just add group by the field before order by like that

```
SELECT p.storepkid, p.selldate AS recentselldate FROM (SELECT storepkid, purchasedatetime AS selldate FROM t_product_purchase UNION ALL SELECT storepkid, starttime AS selldate FROM t_service_purchase UNION ALL SELECT storepkid, selldatetime AS selldatetime FROM t_coupon_purchase) p GROUP BY storepkid ORDER BY recentselldate DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, GROUP BY is giving incorrect records in result set. Please advise further.